# Resaltar filas de toda la tabla

Tags: jquery, laravel, table

Estoy usando una plantilla de Admnistrador para Laravel y estoy agregando unos detalles visuales como resaltar las filas de la tabla, el código funciona bien, pero debido a que tengo más de 100 registros me vi obligada a colocar paginación (paginate:true) para ordenar la informacion.
El problema es que solo funciona el código de "Resaltar" en la página uno, al seleccionar "Siguiente" deja de funcionar el código.

Mi tabla (la paginación de esta tabla se crea con javascript)

```
  <div class="card-body">
                  <table id="example1" width="100"
                    height="10" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr onmouseover="this.className = 'resaltar'">
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Lote</th>
                      <th>OSTHM</th>
                      <th>FTHM</th>
                      
                      

                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody name="listaElementos" id="listaElementos">
                      @foreach($ruta as $r)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$r->idr}}</td>
                        <td name="nombre" id="nombre">{{$r->productos->nombre}}</td>
                        <td><input class='form-control' type="number" id="txt-cant"></td>
                        <td name="OSTHM" id="OSTHM">{{$r->OSTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="FTHM" id="FTHM">{{$r->FTHM}}</td>
                                                   
                           </td>

                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-success" value="Análisis" id="analisis" >
```

My code jquery:

```
   <script>
  $(document).ready(()=>{
    $('tbody tr').hover(function(){
      $(this).find('td').addClass('resaltar');         
    }, function(){
      $(this).find('td'). removeClass('resaltar')        
    });

  });
  </script>
```

My code css:

```
<style>
 .resaltar{
  background-color:#AED6F1 ;
  color: black;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que cuando muestras nuevas paginaciones los tr que insertas en el DOM no existian cuando declaraste el evento hover. Podrias terminada la modificacion del DOM para mostrar la nueva paginacion, volver a declarar el evento hover o mas limpio delegar el evento al elemento padre, en este caso #listaElementos(suponiendo que cuando se refresca la paginacion #listaElementos se mantenga en el DOM).

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(()=>{
    $('body').on('hover', 'tr', function(){
      $(this).toogleClass('resaltar');         
    });
  });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, voy a probar el código

Comment: Pues ahora que pongo el códigoque me pasaste solo se iluminan los th

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta la parte del codigo que se refresca con la paginacion. te propongo delegar el evento al body. Edité el codigo de la respuesta.